# Weird byte ArrayList rewriting its values

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem if I run this code, it all works fine until the moment I am trying to access the values that this method returns. It should generate random byte hashes. It works fine if I am in the big for loop(the one with j counter) but once it is out all the values in the arraylist are of the last value that was added there. That's the system.out.prints where rainbow.get(0).start and rainbow.get(1).start.

In the bottom is also the Chain class.

Where is this getting fucked up?

```
public static ArrayList<Chain> genRainBow(){
    byte[] constant = new byte[8];

    ArrayList<byte[]> hashRed = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    ArrayList<byte[]> variations = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

    ArrayList<Chain> rnbow = new ArrayList<Chain>();

    //rainbow = new ArrayList<Chain>();
    //byte[] start;

    byte[] hash = null;
    int collision = 0;
    int allColl = 0;

    Random rnd = new Random();
    byte[] randomBytes = new byte[8];

    byte[] red;

    byte[] copyHash = null;

    for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){

        hashRed = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        collision = 0;
        rnd.nextBytes(randomBytes);
        red = truncate12(randomBytes);
        byte[] start = red;




        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            //System.out.println(i + " " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(red));
            hash = Main.DES(red, constant);
            //System.out.println( i + " " +DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash));

            red = Main.reductionChain(hash, i);

            if(containsList(hashRed, hash))
                collision++;

            hashRed.add(hash);

            //rainbow.put(red, hash);

        }



        hash = red;
        rnbow.add(new Chain(start, hash));
    //    rainbow.add(new Chain(start, hash));

        System.out.println("STR" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rainbow.get(j).start));

        if(!containsList(variations, hash))
            variations.add(hash);

        System.out.println("Collision: " + collision);
        System.out.println();
        allColl += collision;

    }
    System.out.println("STR" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rainbow.get(0).start));
    System.out.println("STR" + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rainbow.get(1).start));
    System.out.println("variations: " + variations.size());
    System.out.println("all collisions: " + allColl);
    System.out.println();

    return rnbow;
}

package rnbow;

public class Chain {
    byte[] start;
    byte[] end;

    public Chain(byte[] st, byte[] en){
        start = st;
        end = en;
    }


    public byte[] printStart(){
        return start;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a rainbow table I see.

But if all the values are the same as the last, it means you're not doing a new byte[8] anywhere, and are just replacing the bytes in the single array (which you reference several time in your ArrayList).

Comment: thanks, it was actually hidden there, the randomBytes were not initialized in this statement          rnd.nextBytes(randomBytes);